# Responsive block layout

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a design which is that of rows consisting of two blocks.

http://jsfiddle.net/dhxr25m6/

```
<div class="homepageBlockRow">
   <div class="homepageBlock">
      <img src="http://s1059327.instanturl.net/images/HomeTiles/BigJob.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="homepageBlock homepageBlockText orangeBackground" style="height: 372px;">
    ...
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<div class="homepageBlockRow">
   <div class="homepageBlock homepageBlockText greyBackground" style="height: 372px;">
      ...
   </div>
   <div class="homepageBlock">
      <img src="http://s1059327.instanturl.net/images/HomeTiles/Rental.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

The page looks good on a full size monitor but on tablet resolutions the images are about half the height as the text blocks.

I tried scaling up the text block to match the row height, but that doesn't work when the image is smaller.

What would be a good way to scale things so that the images and text are always the same height?

Comment: you can't ever guarantee the height of text will equal exactly to your images. You can get as close as possible but your end goal would be to have the image wrapped so that the text surrounds it or is to the side of the image depending on which side you want it on (right or left...).

Comment: @CayceK Did you look at the fiddle link?

Comment: yea, but I still don't see what you're trying to accomplish. You can shrink the size of your text at smaller screen sizes, but in the end unless you have an exact number of letters based on the height of the image there isn't a way to guarantee both will fit in the same height restrictions. This is because the text can be variable length and size. Using ems in text instead of pixels might make it easier, but they get complicated fast. Do you have a final image of what you want it to look like to allow me to better point at something and say that is possible?

Comment: If you don't mind, hit http://s1059327.instanturl.net/ and scroll down to the bottom. 

It looks nice on a big screen but when you scroll down you end up with the images scaled funky like in jsfiddle. 

I'm looking for the best way to keep a good look at the smaller ipad resolutions. I'm thinking I might need to do some media queries to swap out the current images for different/smaller ones that fit nice.

Comment: You could auto-crop the left and right sides of the images in order to maintain their height...

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle - only issue is you'd have to switch over to background images in css...

http://jsfiddle.net/dhxr25m6/1/

Comment: And here is a way of doing it while maintaining your <img /> tags but it relies on a fixed height... http://jsfiddle.net/dhxr25m6/2/

Comment: @Michael I had a fixed height in there at one point, the issue you run into is that on a larger monitor you end up with too short images again. Background images is a good thought too, but then we have to crop what's shown which I'm not really interested in. The images lose some of their power that way. For example just showing a piece of equipment vs. showing the equipment with a trailer that has a company logo next to it.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to be utilizing flexbox.  That comes with compatibility issues...  Other than that, maybe some javascript to adjust things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 has object-fit property that can achieve this (while retaining the aspect ratio). 
Just add the following code to the css for the image:

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
object-fit:cover;
object-position: 0 0;
```

FYI, I changed the structure of the div definitions a bit and added some height/width/float attributes and you can see a demo here (fiddle doesn't seem to run my code for some reason as mentioned in the comments):
 [object-fit-solution](http://fenildedhia.com/stackoverflow/test2.html)

**RESPONSIVE DESIGN:**

For mobile devices, you will need to write media queries.
Some pointers for that:
1) make the clearfix div to float to left
2) remove floats on image and text blocks. Also make the width to 100%.

Comment: @AndrewWalters Please refer to [this link](http://fenildedhia.com/stackoverflow/test2.html). For some reason, the code doesn't work on fiddle!

Comment: I think we really don't want the image's aspect ratio to get skewed when scaling the screen.

Comment: Ok. Updated answer with solution and demo.